# What is an alternative to "with check option" of oracle in hive

Tags: oracle, hive

I have query in Oracle like this:

```
CREATE VIEW myview
    AS SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE mycolumn = 10
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Now, 'with check option' restricts any sort of update or insert operations on the view.

Is there any function similar to 'with check option' in Hive to restrict insert, update operations?

Answer (score 0):

> "'with check option' restricts any sort of update or insert operations
> on the view."

This is not exactly true. "with check option" prevents a user from updating rows in the source table, through the update-able view, in such a way that they are no longer visible through the view. It does not prevent "any sort" of updates. It is about preserving data integrity, not restricting user access or privileges.

Is the issue you are addressing about preserving data integrity, or about user privileges and security?

If security, then these sorts of things are generally handled in any database simply by not granting insert, update, or delete privileges to a user.

If about data integrity, then this link seems to indicate that there is no "with check option" equivalent in hive (see item F311-04): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Supported+Features%3A++Apache+Hive+3.1

What is the specific issue you are addressing with this approach, both in Oracle and Hive?